# Deploying a Loopback (Node.js) API to Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, loopbackjs

I have a Node.js API built with [Loopback](https://loopback.io/) that I'm having some problems deploying to Azure.

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs) article, so what I've done is basically the following:

- Cloned the API project to the Azure server through Cloud Shell
- Created a new webapp with `az webapp up -n loopback-api` through Cloud Shell from in the project folder
- Created a `app.js` file  at the project's root level, as suggested in [this](http://stevenfollis.com/2016/03/27/deploying-a-loopback-node-js-api-on-azure-web-apps/) article

It seems to be up and running from the looks of Azure Portal, but when I try to access it I'm getting *Service Unavailable*.

What could I be missing?